# How can I backup Samsung Note 10 it if does not work

Tags: samsung, backup, internal-storage, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1, power-options

My Samsung Note 10 went green lines and now it does not turn on. But sometimes when I connect power supply it vibrates. When put on the wirless pad it also vibrates. The phone not the pad. How can I backup the device? Tried connecting to computer it did not pick up the note 10. How can I backup? Can I remove memory from it and plug it in to something elae? I need my old texts and data. Please help? Any good method helps. Thanks!

Comment: Use data partition is encrypted by default. Outside of the phone it is impossible to decrypt. So assuming your phone is not rooted or bootloader unlocked the only way to access is to make your phone boot to the regular Android OS.

Comment: I never rooted the phone. Simple standard android it came with.