# How to use Samsung Dex or Smart Switch with no phone screen

Tags: samsung, data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1, samsung-dex, samsung-smart-switch

My Note 10 screen no longer works. When I connected it to my laptop it asked me to install Dex and I did that. But nothing happens. Smart switch says connect the device but when I do nothing happens. Do I need to approve on my note 10? I can't see the screen so how do I get dex or smart switch or anything to get the files out of the note 10

Comment: No just read it. Note 10  does not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I backup Samsung Note 10 it if does not work](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/248363/how-can-i-backup-samsung-note-10-it-if-does-not-work)